# Como deixar o operador negativo apos o uso do diff() em php

Tags: php, data, diff

Bom tarde. Não sei se ficou muito claro mas o seguinte, uso `date_diff()`, o problema é o que, quando eu converto o intervalo `$intervalo = date_interval_format($resultado, '%a')` se o resultado for menor que 0 o numero fica positivo, e está atrapalhando minha logica, pois preciso que quando o prazo estiver em atrazo, eu consiga identificar, só que quando eu faço a diferença e está atrasado 30 dias (-30), meu codigo está interpretando que está faltando 30 dias, pois está positivo. como posso resolver, código abaixo:

```
$database = date_create($row['expira']);
$datadehoje = date_create();
$resultado = date_diff($database, $datadehoje);
$intervalo = date_interval_format($resultado, '%a');
echo $intervalo;
```

Answer (score 3):

O resultado da comparação é sempre o número de dias mas há um atributo no objeto retornado pelo `date_diff()` chamado `invert` que indica se o valor é positivo ou negativo (zero para números positivos e um para negativos).

```
<?php

    $primeiraData = date_create('2018-12-01');
    $segundaData = date_create('2018-12-31');

    $intervalos[0] = date_diff($primeiraData, $segundaData);
    $intervalos[1] = date_diff($segundaData, $primeiraData);

    foreach ($intervalos as $intervalo){
        $diferenca = (int)$intervalo->format('%R%a');
        echo "'Diferença de " . $diferenca . " dias (" . $intervalo->invert . ")'\n";
    }
?>
```

Rodando o programa ele exibirá isto:

```
'Diferença de 30 dias (0)'
'Diferença de -30 dias (1)'
```

Se você pretende apenas exibir a quantidade de dias na tela pode usar o "%R" na *string* de formatação do valor mas se pretende trabalhar com este valor em algum cálculo precisará usar o `invert` para mudar o sinal.